# Jquery Navigation Menu Not Quite Working as Intended

Tags: jquery, html, menu

I have created a fairly conventional 3 level horizontal drop-down navigation menu with Jquery. However, instead of the third level being offset to the side of the second level, it opens up accordion-style. Closing of the third level is delayed after a mouse-out in order to stop it jumping around too much.

I have just one issue yet to solve. When someone has opened the third level and then goes back to a different first level button and then returns to the original first level button, the third level is still open.

You can see this in http://jsfiddle.net/BHK3C/6.
Hovering on Spain and then Andalucia, will open the third level (Cordoba, etc). If you then go to Morocco and quickly return to Spain, the third level is immediately opened.

I have tried various things like

```
   $(".nav1").hoverIntent( 
        function(){//onmouseover 
            $(this).children("ul").slideDown(1000);
            $(".nav2").children("ul").hide(); 
        },
```

but none of them work. Any suggestions?

SOLUTION
Subsequently I found that there was a variation on my original efforts that did work:

```
   $(".nav1").hoverIntent( 
        function(){//onmouseover 
            $(".nav2").children("ul").hide(); 
            $(this).children("ul").slideDown(1000);
        },
```

The .delay(3000) is necessary to stop the third level closing as soon as the mouse is moved to a different place in the level 2 list. In fact I have found .delay(8000) seems to be about the right setting.

hoverIntent is really useful for stopping the dropdown from dancing around in an undesirable fashion. So far I am using the default settings but I think it needs a little bit of tweaking. It seems to be quite pernickety the second time that you come back to the same place in the level 2 list, so the level 3 is quite reluctant to open.

Thanks to those who replied.

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is merely one of CSS. You have some nested statements in your Fiddle, which may be the root of the issue.

Your second issue is probably because you haven't properly dealt with the handlerOut event.

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 0):

changing the code to this:

```
$(".nav1").hover( 
    function(){//onmouseover 
        $(this).children("ul").slideDown(1000); 
    }, 
    function(){//onmouseout 
        $(this).children("ul").slideUp(1000).children("ul").hide(); 
});
```

hides the children of a level 2 element that has been slid up.

http://jsfiddle.net/BHK3C/7/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want but try to remove `.delay(3000)` when you mouseout the `ul` of `.nav2`

Also, make use of jQuery **[stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)** to end the current animation before starting a new one.

```
$(this).children("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown(1000);
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BHK3C/8/)**